# Can i get code from phone?

Tags: android

I installed my application on  phone , 2 days ago , after I did some changes in classes and I lost code from pc . I don t have backup , but the application with functional code is installed on phone . Can I get back from phone to pc the code? Thank you

Comment: You are asking if is possible to get the .java files from .apk ? In that case there is a way but that doesn't give you the whole structure of the project, the resources. You can google: get .java from .apk android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is "no".  What's installed on the phone is the compiled application, not the source code.  What you can try doing is copy the APK from your phone back to your PC, un-compress it and try decompiling it with one of java decompilers.  If you compiled with debug information, then you might get most of it.  Otherwise you'll get rather messy code that you might be able to use/re-use.